# Having a hard time targeting <img> using :nth-child()

Tags: css

I'm having a hard time targetting the second `<img>` tag to apply a `.css` rule to it but it's not working:

This is my code:

```css
.product-highlights img:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-highlights">
  <div class="grid-container full">
    <div class="grid-x">
      <div class="cell small-4">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Discounts">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cell small-4">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Discounts">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cell small-4">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Discounts">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .product-highlights

Comment: `:nth-of-type` MDN: _The :nth-of-type() CSS pseudo-class matches one or more elements of a given type, based on their position **among a group of siblings**._

Comment: if you want to pick secound image use .product-highlights .grid-x .cell:nth-child(2) img

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I noted in my comment above, `nth-of-type` only looks at siblings, so in your case target the image's parent divs instead:

```css
.product-highlights .cell:nth-of-type(2) img{
  margin: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-highlights">
  <div class="grid-container full">
    <div class="grid-x">
      <div class="cell small-4">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Discounts">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cell small-4">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Discounts">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cell small-4">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Discounts">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

pick secound div that holding image and then apply css to that image

```css
.product-highlights .cell:nth-child(2) img{
  margin: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-highlights">
  <div class="grid-container full">
    <div class="grid-x">
      <div class="cell small-4">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Discounts">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cell small-4">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Discounts">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cell small-4">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Discounts">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```